# Call a Function from Header React Native

Tags: react-native

There are two files `1. Main.js (Header File)` `2. Items.js (The Main Screen)`

Main.js

```
const navigation = useNavigation();


<Tab.Screen name={productsName}
    options={{
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#1DA6FA',
      },
      headerLeft: () => (
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
          <Item title="search" iconName="menu-outline" color="white" onPress={() => alert('menu')} />
        </HeaderButtons>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
          <Item title="Update" iconName="refresh-outline" color="white" onPress={() => //This is  where i'm calling the function />
        </HeaderButtons>
        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
          <Item title="Add Item" iconName="add-outline" color="white" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddItem')} />
        </HeaderButtons>
        </View>
      ),
    }}
    component={Items} />
```

In Items.js there is this `getData()` function i want to call from header

I have tried `navigation.getParam` but it dosn't work

Note - Both are in functional component

Answer (score 0):

```
const itemsRef = useRef();

const onPressHeaderButton = () => {
  itemsRef.current.getData();
}

...

<Tab.Screen 
  name={productsName}
  options={{
    headerRight: () => (<Item title="Update" iconName="refresh-outline" color="white" onPress={onPressHeaderButton}/>)
  }}
  >
  {(props) => <Items ref={itemsRef} {...props} />}
</Tab.Screen>
```

Comment: You should declare your function in Main.js then pass it as props (check this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#children)

Comment: sorry this is not i'm looking for

Comment: If you really need to declare your function in Item.js so you should set a ref on Items.js and call it from Main.js

Something like: itemsRef.current.getData()

Comment: I edited my response, hope it helps